# Fractal image format data importation

Tags: r

I want to load an .fif file in R but i can't find the right way.

There a function in PET package but it did not work because the header should be in a specific format.

Please can any one help me.

Example:

```
library(PET)
readData("data.fif")
Error in readData("data.fif",  : 
  Error reading FIF (Converting)
```

[Here is an example of the data](https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python/tree/master/mne/data/fsaverage).

Comment: I think your question needs a [mcve]

Comment: @R.B Can you provide a download link for the .fif file?

Comment: @jogo ! i put a link to download fif files

Comment: If you look at the source code of the PET package then you see the readData makes a call, which already produces the error  
    
      > fdata <- .Call("loadFile", "data.fif", DebugLevel = "Normal", PACKAGE = "PET")
ReadFIF: Reading `data.fif'

Comment: Can you verify that the header is as described in `help("readData")`?